# MQTT connection creation and subscribe

Tags: ionic-framework, mqtt

I'm setting up a new mqtt conection in my app but there is a problem when i would like to create the main connection of mqtt.

I'm using mqtt.js.

I've tried all what is done in MQTT documentation but nothing happens..

```
mqttFunction(){
  var mqtt = require('mqtt');
  var client = mqtt.connect([{host: 'localhost', port: '1883'},]);

  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(message);
});  
}
```

I expect the output of the mqtt broker to be 'ON' when i asked it to respond.
The error is: ERROR ReferenceError: process is not defined

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your question, attach stack trace of the error and describe in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you followed is intended for Node.js and various other back-end JavaScript frameworks. Even though it uses NPM, Ionic ultimately produces a front-end framework, and its applications run a bit differently.

For example, Ionic programs **may not have a global `process` variable** like Node.js. mqtt.js expects this variable, with code like:

`if (commist.parse(process.argv.slice(2)) !== null){...}`

1. You could [declare a process object](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined/64977), and get past this particular error. Other obstacles could come up.

`var process = {env : {NODE_ENV: 'production'}}`

2. If there are still issues with that, you could try the [instructions for browser usage](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/README.md#browser), which point to a specially compiled version, like https://unpkg.com/mqtt@3.0.0/dist/mqtt.min.js. I have had less luck with mqtt.js in the browser, and you may want an alternative like [web-mqtt-cient](https://github.com/orbitbot/web-mqtt-client) / Paho if more complex connections are involved.

Comment: Ok, thanks i understand, so i think i should use Paho or something like that because specific connection are involved.. 

The main problem is the app works with a backend (linked to a db), Electron, and a Data Dispatcher (to get datas from CAN) and sent to the frontend.. So that's a bit complicated

Comment: mqtt.js is fine for "specific connections", and the things running on the backend should not matter much to a front-end as long as it has all the parameters needed for the connection. I've done better with Paho because its JS library was made for browsers and handles websockets more cleanly.